# How can I stream my ipad app to apple tv?

Tags: ipad, stream

For presenting my app to an group, I want to stream the actual ipad screen wireless to a big screen - I hoped, I could realize that via Apple TV 2, but I do not find the right way.
Any suggestions?
(I don´t want to stream video, audio, photos - I want´t to stream the using of my app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have IOS 5, it is already built in. Double click the menu button and scroll to the left, click on the Airplay icon and turn mirroring on.

Comment: that´s what I thought - but I don´t get the option "mirroring" - I have the latest software versions for iPad and Apple TV 2. My iPad sees the Apple TV, I can stream photos + video etc., but I can not find the mirroring-option. Do I have to enable some option somewhere?

Comment: When you double-click and scroll to the left do you see the Airplay icon, with the Music Note in Orange on the Right, and the Play controls in the center?

Comment: Yes, I do. When I press the AirPlay-Button, I can select between iPad, my AirPort Express and my Apple TV. I select the Apple TV, but nothing happens.

Comment: SOLVED!!  :)   my fault - the os-update for the apple tv was not properly installed - I started the update again and now everything is fine. Thanks to Robert for supporting.